# how to add actions in magento ACL permissions in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i wanted to add custom module actions like create, edit and delete need to be added in ACL permissions, can anyone help me how we do that, thanks in advance

Comment: please elaborate on what you want to achieve and tell us what you have tried so far, otherwise no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the sales module as inspiration.
In the `adminhtml.xml` of the module you will [find this](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/adminhtml.xml#L89):

```
                        <order translate="title">
                            <title>Orders</title>
                            <children>
                                <actions translate="title">
                                    <title>Actions</title>
                                    <children>
                                        <create translate="title"><title>Create</title></create>
                                        <view translate="title"><title>View</title></view>
                                        <email translate="title"><title>Send Order Email</title></email>
                                        <reorder translate="title"><title>Reorder</title></reorder>
                                        <edit translate="title"><title>Edit</title></edit>
                                        <cancel translate="title"><title>Cancel</title></cancel>
                                        <review_payment translate="title"><title>Accept or Deny Payment</title></review_payment>
                                        <capture translate="title"><title>Capture</title></capture>
                                        <invoice translate="title"><title>Invoice</title></invoice>
                                        <creditmemo translate="title"><title>Credit Memos</title></creditmemo>
                                        <hold translate="title"><title>Hold</title></hold>
                                        <unhold translate="title"><title>Unhold</title></unhold>
                                        <ship translate="title"><title>Ship</title></ship>
                                        <comment translate="title"><title>Comment</title></comment>
                                        <reorder translate="title"><title>Reorder</title></reorder>
                                        <emails translate="title"><title>Send Sales Emails</title></emails>
                                    </children>
                                </actions>
                            </children>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </order>
```

Every action you can do is listed in there.
Then, in the controller you need to check if you have access depending on the action. Similar to this [code here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php#L660):

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    $action = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getActionName());
    switch ($action) {
        case 'hold':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/hold';
            break;
        case 'unhold':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/unhold';
            break;
        case 'email':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/email';
            break;
        case 'cancel':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/cancel';
            break;
        case 'view':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/view';
            break;
        case 'addcomment':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/comment';
            break;
        case 'creditmemos':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/creditmemo';
            break;
        case 'reviewpayment':
            $aclResource = 'sales/order/actions/review_payment';
            break;
        default:
            $aclResource = 'sales/order';
            break;
    }
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($aclResource);
}
```

and you can check if you can add a button or not similar [to this](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php#L158)

```
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
        ));
    }
```