# How to Remove Backend Bulk Action Buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, massaction

In the backend of magento, under `Sales> Orders`, `Catalog> Manage Products` and `Clients> Manage Clients`, you have the field of actions from which one of them is to exclude and in this case excludes all items from which they are selected.

I was wondering if I would have some way to remove the field from all those pages in the magento backend, so I can avoid deleting crucial bulk information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution I found quick and simple to do this is using css, giving a `display:none` in the div that contains the input on the referring pages.

**`CSS` code:**

```
body.adminhtml-sales-order-index .massaction .entry-edit, body.adminhtml-catalog-product-index .massaction .entry-edit, body.adminhtml-customer-index .massaction .entry-edit{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up! Setting element to `display:none` just hides them, but they are still executable ...

At the end it looks like Magentos code is not complete/continues.

The visibility of the massaction dropdown (and it options) should be covered by Magentos ACL settings.

See [how to add actions in magento ACL permissions in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76235/how-to-add-actions-in-magento-acl-permissions-in-magento)

... this **should** be done for every massaction.

---

So you can also create a module that adds permissions to Magentos role management and rewrite `isAllowed()` method in associated controller.